# Read binary data and convert it into .wav or mp3 audio file

Tags: php

i am developing an web application in which i have to read binary from database base actually this is audio which is saved in the form or binary. how to convert this binary into wav or mp3 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't touch the binary data and it's still in its original binary wav/mp3 form, you *have* the audio file. Just write it to a file to make it an actual file:

```
file_put_contents('sound.wav', $binaryData);
```

Comment: I have a same issue. Do you know how to do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'convert' it, but if you want to allow a user to download an mp3 or wav file you need to set the correct headers.

You can set the headers for an mp3 download using the following code.

```
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . $len);
```

Note, you will need to know the length of the mp3 data.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php for more information on setting headers.